# Directory Structure for Large Amount of Images

Tags: file, directory, md5

I have approximately 8 million images which consists of an original image and 4 resized images. Currently they are all contained in a single directory which serves the images via HTTP. We are looking to move to reorganize the files into a new directory structure. What would be the most efficient method to organize images with a naming scheme of 32 mixed alphanumeric characters and .jpg at the end.

Comment: It really depends on the distribution of the filenames across the entire alphabet space. Can you give more insight into your particular distribution, or is it basically uniform?

Comment: Why would the naming scheme matter at all? Why not just 0.jpg, 1.jpg, ..., 7999999.jpg, 8000000.jpg?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Folder Structure for storing millions of images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256835/folder-structure-for-storing-millions-of-images)